# ros2 nav2 waypoint error - foxy

Tags: yaml, collision, parameter, nav2

I'm using Nav2 on ROS2 foxy.

After mapping, whever I set goal_pose nav2 makes correct waypoint.

But near the corner, the waypoint is suddenly changed too close to move.
So that every time the robot crash.

Even I change parameters like, inflation radius, footprint, cost_scaling factor,
rviz map display the result, but the robot ignore the wall inflation because waypoint created too close to the wall.

[image]

[image]

I do not know what is problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup, configuration files, etc. to be able to help you.